# Magento : dev adding input for custom price

Tags: magento

i m developping an extention for a company and i wanna know how to add input to localhost//sony-vaio-vgn-txn27n-b-11-1-notebook-pc.html page.

this is image shows where i wanna show it : 
[image]

```
_________
```

anyone knows how to do this ?

Thank you !

Comment: you can use product custom option

Comment: where and how can i do this by developpement

Comment: https://kamal250.wordpress.com/tag/create-custom-option-programmatically-in-magento/ or http://pravams.com/2011/05/25/magento-create-custom-options-dynamically/

Comment: seems u don't understand what i mean see this link : http://custom-price-extensions.magentoext.com/sony-vaio-vgn-txn27n-b-11-1-notebook-pc.html

Comment: It works, right? I can put in any price I want for the TV - it's great. I'm getting one for $67. What is your question? Do you want to display additional text inside the input box next to the text $2999.99?

Comment: @Malachy yes u can put the price u want but it has to be greater than the min price and for the input i wanna put it where the price is displayed :p and i can't find how to do that :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be patient. Do not use $('#myDiv').hide() - it is not the answer. You should be looking to a .phtml file

```
[your theme or your module]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

That .phtml file should tell you which .phtml file is generating the HTML for the input box, from there you should edit the .phtml file that generates the input box and change the input box value from '$2999.99' to 'must be greater than $2000' or whatever you want to put in the input box.