# Magento : Hide html elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, magento

I'm developing an extension and I want to know how to hide an `html` element:

I tried this code, but it didn't work

```
$$('#myDiv').hide();
```

Where is my error?

Comment: Why are you using 2 $ signs?

Comment: `$('#myDiv').hide();` and look on your error console what the error is.

Comment: why the tag `magento` removed?

Comment: $$ its magento using prototype.js not the real jquery and someone edited my question :(

Comment: what a mess! everyone editing the question without knowing the exact problem with added tags ([tag:magento])

Comment: yep the one who edited the quetion thinks i m idiot but he is !!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially this question was tagged [magento](/questions/tagged/magento).
So I assume the issue is inside a magento project.
Magento uses prototype by default.
In prototype you can hide an element like this.

```
$('element_id_here').hide();
```

`$` means `getElementById`.

If you want to hide a set of elements, let's say with the class `some_class` do this:

```
$$('.some_class').each (function(elem){
    $(elem).hide();
})
```

it also works for ids the same way but it's kind of useless since the id must be unique in the page.

```
$$('#myDiv').each (function(elem){
    $(elem).hide();
})
```

Comment: ok @Marius thanks that worked the real issue is this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475351/magento-dev-adding-input-for-custom-price   ; do u have any idea because i m working with an idea that i don't think its a good one !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: the $('element_id_here').hide(); give me that error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hide' of null

Comment: This means that the element with id `element_id_here` does not exist

Comment: ok thats good solved with
 $$('#myDiv').each (function(elem){
    $(elem).hide();
})

now i wanna insert an element how seems to me @Marius u r pro in magento :p

Answer (score 4):

In Jquery

```
$('#myDiv').hide(); //You have to include jquery library in your file
```

In Javascript

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible typo? Extra "$".

Jquery:

```
  $('#myDiv').hide();
```

And are you trying to do it on a click?

Answer (score 1):

only one dollar sign needed

```
$('#myDiv').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

as when I first see this post it contains a [magento](/questions/tagged/magento) tag. And many of the beginners do have problem with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) and [prototype](/questions/tagged/prototype) in magento.

the code to hide html with `id` selector in `jquery` is:

```
$('#myDiv').hide(); //# for id selector
```

but for prototype, its:

```
$('myDiv').hide(); //no # needed for id selector
```

but even if it do not work then open `web developer tool` (Ctrl + Shift + C) of your browser and look for `console` tab. there you might be getting error.